# Why this generic return type of a method is not valid

Tags: java, generics, interface, return-value

I don't get it. In java I'm allowed to declare an interface as a return type of a method, like:

```
public List<String> get(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

if I now have an interface lets say `I` and a class `C` implementing it, why I'm not allowed to define like this:

```
public List<I> get(){
    return new ArrayList<C>();
}
```

I know the solution to create an `ArrayList<I>` and add `C` to it, but I'm wondering why I'm not allowed to declare it like the one above. I thought that every `C` is also a `I` though it should be no problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do this because `List<I>` and `List<C>` are incompatible types.

You can do this, however

```
public List<? extends I> get(){
    return new ArrayList<C>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are running into an issue with co- and contravariance. To put it short: your `List<I>` interface has also a method `Add`, which expects an instance of `I`, but not every `I` will in fact be implemented by `C`, as any other class may also implement `I`. Therefore you'll end up with typecasting issues.